# Add the page number of an splitted wordpress post/page to the shortlink

Tags: wordpress

I use permalinks on my WordPress website, but I want to offer visitors an short-link.
I came up with this code which gives me an short-link in an shortcode what is useful for me,
but I often use  on my site which splits the page in multiple sub-pages, the permalink gets a number added for each sub page in the end.
Is there the possibility to add the actual sub page to the shortlink?

```
function custom_get_shortlink($post_id) {
    if (!$post_id) {
        return false;
    }
    $shortlink = wp_get_shortlink($post_id);
    return $shortlink;
}
function display_custom_shortlink() {
    // Hole die Post-ID
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $shortlink = custom_get_shortlink($post_id);
    if ($shortlink) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($shortlink) . '">Kurzlink</a>';
    }
}
function custom_shortlink_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    display_custom_shortlink();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_shortlink', 'custom_shortlink_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the code in the actual page template?

If so, you have access to the **$page var**, which gives you the current page of a page/blog.

For example:
https://site.local/test-page/2/

```
echo $page
```

will output "2"

So, you can do something like that

```
$shortlink = custom_get_shortlink($post_id).'/'.$page;
```

Comment: Well with this I get something like this https://example.com?p=11592/3 but all what this does is to redirect me to the first page of the article with the ID. /3 is not recognized and removed. I found out that I can use ?p=11592&page=3 which will be translated to /pagename/?page=3 which sends me to page 3 but this is still not optimal because it should rewrite the ?page=3 to  just /3.